# Evaluating boolean expressions in Python

Tags: python, boolean

```
11 % 14 == 11 and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
```

When I type it into Python it tells me that the statement is false.

```
if  11 % 14 == 11 and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

From my understanding 11 % 14 == 11 is true, 6 * 3 = 18 // 4 is 4 so that would be true, and 20 // 6 would be 3 so that should be true as well? Can someone explain to me how it is false?

Comment: Take a look at [Operator Precedence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm)

Comment: Why didn't you just run the parts separately to see? No need for your "understanding" if you can just run things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 11 % 14 == 11 and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
2. 11 == 11 and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
3. True and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
4. True and ( 18 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
5. True and ( 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
6. True and ( False or 20 // 6 != 3)
7. True and ( False or 3 != 3)
8. True and ( False or False)
9. True and ( False)

   - answer -- False

Answer (score 5):

You missed two critical items:

```
6 * 3 // 4 > 4
```

Is False: 4 is not greater than 4.  Similarly,

```
20 // 6 != 3
```

Is False: 3 is equal to 3.

Next time, you might go into interpreter mode and find out on your own, using divide-and-conquer:

```
>>> 11 % 14 == 11 and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
False
>>> 11 % 14 == 11
True
>>> 6 * 3 // 4 > 4
False
>>> 20 // 6 != 3
False
>>> 6 * 3 // 4
4
>>> 20 // 6
3
>>>
```

Finally, please note that your **if** statement is redundant.  You can simply use

```
print 11 % 14 == 11 and ( 6 * 3 // 4 > 4 or 20 // 6 != 3)
```

The resulting value is a printable Boolean constant.

Answer (score 3):

Here `11 % 14 == 11` is `True`

Next, `6 * 3 // 4 > 4` is `False`

And, `20 // 6 != 3` is `False`

So, `True and (False or False)` would be `False`